# QuickBooks Desktop Web Connector Autorun a Request Queue

Tags: php, quickbooks

I'm using quickbooks desktop. I want to dump the `CustomerQueryRq` response every 5 minutes. I started on top of ConsoliBYTE `docs/web_connector/example_app_web_connector`

---

#### What I want to do:

I'm looking for a way where I don't have to visit the handler.php file every 5 minutes to trigger the queue. I believe there's a better way.

---

#### Here's what I did:

1. Created and registered a `.qwc` file in web connector
2. Modified the config, qbwc, handler and functions files
3. Created cron job that calls the handler.php file every 5 minutes.
   It gives me a json file like this: [json file](https://pastebin.com/2ztQbJcL) which is exactly what I want.

qbwc.php:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/config.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/functions.php';

// Map QuickBooks actions to handler functions
$map = array(
    QUICKBOOKS_QUERY_CUSTOMER => array( '_quickbooks_customer_query_request', '_quickbooks_customer_query_response' ),
    );

$Server = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server($dsn, $map, $errmap, $hooks, $log_level, $soapserver, QUICKBOOKS_WSDL, $soap_options, $handler_options, $driver_options, $callback_options);
$response = $Server->handle(true, true);
```

functions.php:

```
function _quickbooks_customer_query_request($ListID = null, $FullName = null)
{
    $xml = '
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <?qbxml version="2.0"?>
        <QBXML>
          <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
            <CustomerQueryRq />
          </QBXMLMsgsRq>
        </QBXML>
        ';
    return $xml;
}

function _quickbooks_customer_query_response($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents)
{   
    $xmlData = simplexml_load_string($xml);
    $json = json_encode($xmlData->QBXMLMsgsRs->CustomerQueryRs, true);
    file_put_contents('customerDump.json', $json);
}
```

handler.php:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/config.php';

    // Queue up the customer dump
    $Queue = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue($con);
    $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_QUERY_CUSTOMER, 2);
    
    die('Great, queued up customer dump!');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to make it so that every time the Web Connector connects, it queues up the request you want to run.

To do that:

**Register a hook function which runs whenever the Web Connector connects**

```
$hooks = array(
    QuickBooks_WebConnector_Handlers::HOOK_LOGINSUCCESS => 'your_function_name_here',   // call this whenever a successful login occurs
    );
```

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/web_connector/example_web_connector_import.php#L125

**Make that function throw something into the queue**

```
function _quickbooks_hook_loginsuccess($requestID, $user, $hook, &$err, $hook_data, $callback_config)
{
    // For new users, we need to set up a few things
    // Fetch the queue instance
    $Queue = QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue_Singleton::getInstance();

    // Queue stuff up
    $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_QUERY_CUSTOMER, 2);
}
```

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/web_connector/example_web_connector_import.php#L219

So, every time the Web Connector connects your thing gets stuffed into the queue and processed. No `cron` job required.

Comment: Thanks! It's perfect!